In PyQT 5, always show a QCombobox using QStyledItemDelegate in QTableView (Not just when a cell is being edited)
I'm subclassing QStyledItemDelegate to show a dropdown QCombobox in a QTableView. The delegate detects the dataType from the table's model, and if the dataType == EnumMeta, shows a dropdown list of options.
With my current implementation, the dropdown is only displayed after a user double clicks a table cell. The user must then click the dropdown again to show the available options.
Question:
How do I always show the QCombobox, and have it open immediately when the user clicks the table cell?
Example Code
from enum import EnumMeta
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import (
    QStyledItemDelegate,
    QWidget,
    QComboBox,
)
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QPainter
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QModelIndex, QSize, QAbstractItemModel, Qt

from .shared_constants import CustomRoles


class BGCustomDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(BGCustomDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setParent(parent)

    def paint(self, painter: QPainter, option, index: QModelIndex) -> None:
        QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)

    def sizeHint(self, option, index: QModelIndex) -> QSize:
        return QStyledItemDelegate.sizeHint(self, option, index)

    def createEditor(self, parent: QWidget, option, index: QModelIndex) -> QWidget:
        if index.data(CustomRoles.dataType.value) == EnumMeta:
            editor = QComboBox(parent)
            allowed_values_enum: EnumMeta = index.data(CustomRoles.allowedValues.value)
            allowed_values = [e.value for e in allowed_values_enum]
            editor.addItems(allowed_values)
            return editor
        else:
            return QStyledItemDelegate.createEditor(self, parent, option, index)

    def setEditorData(self, editor: QWidget, index: QModelIndex) -> None:
        if index.data(CustomRoles.dataType.value) == EnumMeta:
            editor: QComboBox

            current_value = index.data(Qt.EditRole)
            combo_index = editor.findText(current_value)
            if combo_index >= 0:
                editor.setCurrentIndex(combo_index)
        else:
            QStyledItemDelegate.setEditorData(self, editor, index)

    def setModelData(
        self, editor: QWidget, model: QAbstractItemModel, index: QModelIndex
    ) -> None:
        if index.data(CustomRoles.dataType.value) == EnumMeta:
            editor: QComboBox
            current_value = editor.currentText()
            model.setData(index, current_value, Qt.EditRole)
        else:
            QStyledItemDelegate.setModelData(self, editor, model, index)


Use openPersistentEditor(): for example, table.openPersistentEditor(table.model().index(row, column)) (while iterating through cells). If you want to automatically show the combobox only when the item data is consistent with the type, then first check the data type before calling the function. If you need a more thorough answer, please provide a proper [mre] including sample data to work with.
